# synchronized increment an int value

Tags: java, multithreading

Why this program doesn`t display 2000 at every execution? I know that I can use AtomicInteger, but I am curious.

```
class Increment extends Thread{
     static Integer i=new Integer(0);

    public void run(){

        for(int j=1;j<=1000;j++){
            synchronized (i) {
                i++;
            }
        }

    }
}


public class Puzzle {
    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        Thread t1=new Increment();
        Thread t2=new Increment();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        }catch (InterruptedException r){}
        System.out.println(Increment.i);    
    }    
}
```

Comment: You have a race condition due to the use of i as the lock, change synchronized(i) to Increment.class

Comment: What is i? Its not declared anywhere.

Comment: Without `volatile`, the compiler might do some unwanted optimisations.

Comment: @Zhuinden it doesn't have to be volatile as it is accessed within a synchronized block.

Comment: `volatile` wouldn’t fix that problem.

Comment: `<offtopic>` Please use `Integer.valueOf()` instead of `new Integer()`.

Comment: @Holger this is very dejavu because this isn't the first time I see this problem on SO and yet I still don't realize the error... you are right, the Object monitor still changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You synchronize on a mutable variable `i`. This variable changes its value each time, therefore each time you acquire a lock on another object. Each thread thus acquires a non-contended lock and can proceed simultaneously, as if no synchronization was in place.

Lesson: use a dedicated `private static final Object lock = new Object()` as a lock.

Comment: ohhhhhhh that's smart. I didn't realize that even though I have seen this error on SO before - basically that's why it's good practice to use a `private final Object syncObject = new Object();` as a monitor instead of the object itself if the object can change (which it does with ++ in this case)

Comment: "use a dedicated final Object" shouldn't it read "use a dedicated final static Object" ? Especially in this case.

Comment: An Object can't be static.  A variable can be static.

Comment: @peter.petrov I wanted to phrase it with that part "factored out" but you are right, it will cause misinterpretation. I added `static`.

Comment: The emphasis must be on the fact that it has to be the *same object* all the time. You could store the same reference in different non-`static` variables (though it doesn’t make much sense). You could also use `synchronized(Increment.class)` without an additional variable.

Comment: @Holger There is an additional benefit if you use a *private* object to prevent anyone not participating in your API to acquire this lock.

Comment: That’s right, using `private static final` has the clear advantage of not exposing the synchronization. But the programmer has to be aware that `static synchronized` methods use a different lock object then. I prefer `private` locks too.